# Printing Column Tables in Java Using printf

Tags: java, formatting, printf, rows

I am trying to print column tables using printf in Java. How can I go about moving theses columns under each other?

**Currently I am getting this:** [image]

**But this is what I want:** [image]

*Here is my code*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabTimeTable{

   public static void main(String [] args){
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Time Table:");

   System.out.print("Number (1-10): ");
   int number1 = input.nextInt();
   int number2 = (number1+1);
   int number3 = (number2+1);
   int number4 = (number3+1);
   int number5 = (number4+1);
   int number6 = (number5+1);
   int number7 = (number6+1);
   int number8 = (number7+1);
   int number9 = (number8+1);
   int number10 = (number9+1);


      for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){

         System.out.printf("%2d * %2d = %2d", i, number1, (number1*i));
         System.out.printf("%10d * %2d = %2d", i, number2, (number2*i));
         System.out.printf("%10d * %2d = %2d", i, number3, (number3*i));
         System.out.printf("%10d * %2d = %2d", i, number4, (number4*i));
         System.out.printf("%10d * %2d = %2d", i, number5, (number5*i));
         System.out.printf("%10d * %2d = %2d", i, number6, (number6*i));
         System.out.printf("%10d * %2d = %2d", i, number7, (number7*i));
         System.out.printf("%10d * %2d = %2d", i, number8, (number8*i));
         System.out.printf("%10d * %2d = %2d", i, number9, (number9*i));
         System.out.printf("%10d * %2d = %2d", i, number10, (number10*i));
         System.out.println();

      }


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` doesn't add a newline to the end of the output, for that you should probably use `%n`

Next, you need to leave a number of blank spaces between the two columns, this can easily be established by using `%10s`, where `10` is the number of characters you want the two columns separated from.

After that, you just need to decide if you want to do all in one statement...

```
System.out.printf("%2d * %2d = %2d%10s%2d * %2d = %2d%n", index, multiplier, (multiplier * index), "", index, multiplier + 1, ((multiplier + 1) * index));
```

or use multiple statements...

```
System.out.printf("%2d * %2d = %2d", index, multiplier, (multiplier * index));
System.out.printf("%10s%2d * %2d = %2d%n", "", index, multiplier + 1, ((multiplier + 1) * index));
```

## Runnable example...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int multiplier = 1;
        for (int index = 1; index < 11; index++) {
            //System.out.printf("%2d * %2d = %2d%10s%2d * %2d = %2d%n", index, multiplier, (multiplier * index), "", index, multiplier + 1, ((multiplier + 1) * index));
            System.out.printf("%2d * %2d = %2d", index, multiplier, (multiplier * index));
            System.out.printf("%10s%2d * %2d = %2d%n", "", index, multiplier + 1, ((multiplier + 1) * index));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't disagree with closing the question, but I think I voted for "asking for debugging assistance..." instead

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Agreeded - `JTree` is to complex to work on with assumptions alone